# emberdata 1.13 convert json to JSONAPI

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jsonserializer, json-api

im using Ember Data 1.13.3. and i want to convert my old JSON format to new **JSONAPI** format using  normalizeResponse in JSONAPISerializer.

for example i have my json coming from web service like

```js
{
  user: { id: 1, name: 'wecc', accounts: [1, 2] },
  accounts: [
    { id: 1, email: 'wecc@sweden.se' },
    { id: 2, email: 'wecc@greece.gr' }
  ]
}
```

now in my JSONAPISerializer how can i get the JSONAPI format out of my old json. im getting old format. but i want that format converted automatically into JSONAPI. like below one

```js
{
  data: { 
    id: '1', 
    type: 'user', 
    attributes: {
      name: 'wecc'
    }, 
    relationships: {
      accounts: {
        data: [
          { id: '1', type: 'account' },
          { id: '2', type: 'account' }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  included: [{ 
    id: '1',
    type: 'account',
    attributes: {
      email: 'wecc@sweden.se'
    }
  }, {
    id: '2',
    type: 'account',
    attributes: {
      email: 'wecc@greece.gr'
    }
  }]
}
```

i found some help from ember itself.

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_internal-format-change-to-json-api
they recommand to use **normalizeResponse**

Answer (score 0):

It won't happen automatically. If you are also in control of your REST API I'd recommend normalizing the data on the server itself. Otherwise as you suggested it will have to happen within `normalizeResponse`, but with custom code written to match your data format.

Another solution is to keep using the `RESTSerializer` for now and wait until the JSON API specification gets a bit more popular. Tools will likely be released for most server frameworks to provide standard JSON API payloads in the coming months.

Comment: thanks @PedroCheckos ...i found some way around to do that. You have to change your Ember RESTAdapter to ***JSONAPIAdapter*** and in your ***ember-data*** library(im using version1.13.3) change the `isNewSerializerAPI: false`, to ***true***...and in the end return of one method in library named `_normalizeResponse` console the return data  like ....   `console.log( JSON.stringify(documentHash)); ` so whenever your adapter will ask for request this will show you the **JSONAPI** format of your data in browser console...